# Fatal Error : call to a member function mysql query on resource

Tags: php

I need help because I got an error message like  **"call to a member function mysql query on resource"**

Here is my code:

```html
<?php
include "koneksi.php";
$id_data = $_GET['id_data'];
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0); // disable the time limit for this script
 

$query = "SELECT * FROM kinerja WHERE id_data = $id_data";
$hasil_data = $koneksi->query($query);

if ($hasil_data->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $hasil_data->mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
      $filename = $row['nama_file'];
  }
}

$path = "../admin/files/"; // change the path to fit your websites document structure
 
//$dl_file = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).]|[\.]{2,})", '', $_GET['download_file']); // simple file name validation
//$dl_file = filter_var($dl_file, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); // Remove (more) invalid characters
$fullPath = $path.$filename;
 
if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a file download
        break;
        // add more headers for other content types here
        default;
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
    }
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;

?>
```

I need help for this code, I really apreciate any help. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: check your database connection and try `$hasil_data = mysqli_query('query');`

Comment: do you have the specific line that the problem occurs?

Comment: Mahmud : hi Mahmud, thanks for your help, but the error still exist,
tony : hi tony, the problem occurs on line 9, really sorry if my grammar so badly :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is somewhere in `koneksi.php`. I would guess it's near the function `query()` in that class. If you include that class it would be easier to spot the error.

Comment: hi @cjohansson, here the code of koneksi.php

<?php
$servername   = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "siapops";

// Create connection
$koneksi = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($koneksi->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $koneksi->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connected successfully";
?>

Comment: Replace `include "koneksi.php";` with `require("koneksi.php");`. Maybe the file can't be found. If that doesn't work try this `require("koneksi.php"); global $koneksi;`